# Automatically assign authentication token in .NET

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, httpmodule

I have implemented forms authentication with a .NET Membership Provider but I also want users to be able to login with Facebook. Once authenticated with Facebook, I want to automatically assign a .NET authentication token to the user. I have a `HttpModule` that is detecting the FB authentication but all my attempts to manually generate an authentication token have come up short.

I tried

- `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`
- `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` + `Response.Cookies.Add`
- `new FormsAuthenticationTicket(...)` a la [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx)
- In an `HttpModule` vs `Page`

Plus a few other desperate attempts. Nothing seems to work. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out someone else had registered another module in the solution that was interfering with `HttpRequest` and the authentication pieces. After I got rid of that, `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...)` worked fine.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Proposed way is using [WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx)

Comment: WIF separates source and consumer of identity, and provides simple API to create user token from any source.

Comment: sounds very powerful, appropriate and complicated :/ what is your experience with WIF? is it easy to plug in and get started?

Comment: Couple year ago I implemented WIF-like solution for multiple identity sources. Nowdays WIF used in main Microsoft Poducts like SharePoint and Azure. WIF a lot easier than implement flexible multi-identity solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
// Create a new ticket used for authentication
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, false);
// Create a new ticket used for authentication
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
   1, // Ticket version
   UserName.Text, // Username associated with ticket
   DateTime.Now, // Date/time issued
   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Date/time to expire
   false, // "true" for a persistent user cookie
   "Admin", // User-data, in this case the roles
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);// Path cookie valid for

// Encrypt the cookie using the machine key for secure transport
string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, // Name of auth cookie
   hash); // Hashed ticket

// Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

// Add the cookie to the list for outgoing response
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: I already tried this and it didnt appear to work. Will `Request.IsAuthenticated == true` using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

After you `SetCookieAuth` you need to do a redirect to give the HttpModule a chance to fire and set the `HttpContext.User` property.